# Angular JS Controller not working while using with .js file

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm New to Angular JS. I'm trying a simple Example but it seemed to be not working.

I created a script.js with following code:-

var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []).controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "AngularJS Tutorial";
});

And HtmlPage1.html :-

```
<script src="Script.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script> </head> <body>
 <div ng-app="myModule">
     <div ng-controller="myController">
         {{ message }}
     </div>
 </div>
```

But I'm getting this result:-

{{ message }}

I don't know what's wrong . Please Help...

Comment: start by looking in browser console...the error `angular is not defined` would be a big clue....always check console first!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load `Script.js` after loading reference of `angular.js`, because your module declaration needs the reference of angular.

You need to do is make sure that the angular module is created before you attempt to register controller on it .

```
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>  
<script src="Script.js"></script>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/y0Hq4STsh2fmt8D0YsM8?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Script.js"></script> </head> <body>
<div ng-app="myModule">
 <div ng-controller="myController">
     {{ message }}
 </div>
</div>
```

Include controller after angular library (y)

Comment: What is the difference from the answer i posted?

Comment: Yours and mine is same ,I was few seconds later i think . Should I delete it ?

Comment: @Ujjwalkaushik no. This situation happens all the time, especially when answer is obvious and there is only one potential code change

Comment: @Ujjwalkaushik no, i was wondering if there is any difference! its ok to keep

Comment: ok @charlietfl ,but  I should try to comment  on these situations first :(

Comment: What difference does it makes to load script before or after the angular.js

Comment: that's because ,You need to load angular library first before using it .

Comment: Oh I got it now. Thanks. It makes sense.

Comment: @Deepak  explanation is given in my answer